# Are PROCEDUREs preferable to FUNCTIONs in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

If I have a logical task that has a single return value, is there any rule or guideline whether a FUNCTION or PROCEDURE should be used in MySQL? Are there specific use-cases where a FUNCTION is better than a PROCEDURE or vice versa?

I saw a related thread ( [Stored procedures and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117427/stored-procedures-and-functions) ) but that is focused on SQL Server and I imagine this is quite an implementation-specific question; what is the answer for MySQL?

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744209/mysql-stored-procedure-vs-function-which-would-i-use-when

Comment: I think that answers this - can I mark my own question to be closed/merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John stated, my comment was already the answer.

Just read: [MySQL stored procedure vs function, which would I use when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744209/mysql-stored-procedure-vs-function-which-would-i-use-when)

Answer (score 1):

Functions/procedures return values, functions can be called inside another statement, procedures are statements, and cannot be called in another statement.